# Setting up a server on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I spun up a Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Google Cloud Platform and tried following steps one to three on [setting the VM up](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04).

Instead of `ssh root@your_server_ip` (step one), I just went to the console, clicked on the drop-down under the Connect column in "VM instances" and selected "Open in browser window". Then I followed steps two and three to create a new user and to give it root privileges.

Skipping the 'recommended' steps 4 and 5, I tried step 6 to do a test log in by activating the Cloud Shell. But `ssh [user created in step 2]@your_server_ip`, where `your_server_ip` is the "External IP" in the "VM instances" page results in "Permission denied (publickey)."

Why is this?

Comment: If you skipped the step 4, you never generated a key pair for your new user. Why would you expect you'll be able to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martheen comment is right, you need to generate the ssh key pair in order to ssh.

As you are using the Google Cloud platform I will point you to the documentation related there. 
You can use the GCP ways to connect to the instance [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools).

Other methods to connect you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#provide-key).